# JavaScript promises not passing data to .then unless I explicitly use Promise.resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

My code gets a translation from Google translate, pushes the translation into an array, and then passes the translation array to the next code block. Or it doesn't, depending on the syntax. This works:

```
translate.translate(text, target)
.then(function(results) {
  translation = results[0];
  translationArray.push(translation);
  return Promise.resolve(translationArray);
})
.then(function(translationArray) {
  console.log(translationArray);
```

This code doesn't work:

```
translate.translate(text, target)
.then(function(results) {
  translation = results[0];
  return translationArray.push(translation);
})
.then(function(translationArray) {
  console.log(translationArray);
```

`translationArray` logs as `1`. What does `1` mean? Why do I need to explicitly use `Promise.resolve`?

I tried this, it doesn't help:

```
const finalPromise = translate.translate(text, target)
.then(function(results) {
   translation = results[0];
   return translationArray.push(translation);
  })
.then(function(translationArray) {
   console.log(translationArray);
```

Comment: It would be kind-of nice if `.push()` did return the array reference but alas.

Comment: @Pointy `const push = (a, ...elements) => (a.push(...elements), a)` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array. If your array is empty then after adding an element the new length is `1`. That's where the `1` comes from.

You don't have to use `Promise.resolve`, you just need `return translationArray;`.